# Sliding drawer equivalent in iOS

Tags: ios, slidingdrawer

After wasting lot of time searching, I am finally posting this question, hoping I get an answer.

I want to have a widget in iOS, which has the similar functionality of Sliding Drawer in Android. (Like the bar at the bottom, and on pulling it, it shows up a new view).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've been working on an interesting solution to this. It's a floating style navigation drawer. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/JVillella/JVFloatingDrawer).

Comment: I did a google search on "iOS slide-out drawer library" and found 3 or 4 right off the bat. You might try using somebody else's pre-built library, or you could write your own using a custom UIView and a pan gesture recognizer. That's what I did for my company's app, FaceDancer.

Answer (score 3):

A few similar questions that might help you out:

[Making a pull out tray - (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531373/making-a-pull-out-tray-ios)

[iOS: Sliding UIView on/off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875145/ios-sliding-uiview-on-off-screen)

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a drawer container controller and put it up on Github:
https://github.com/saldavonschwartz/DrawerContainerController

While not exactly the same (you are asking about a vertical single view sliding up/down), you might want to download the code and take a look. My approach might as well work for what you are trying to do: basically, creating a container controller which can host another controller and its view and present its view in a custom way.

Specifically, you might want to look at:

- `-replaceContainedController:forIdentifier:` for how you would go about adding child view controllers the 'Apple' way.
- `-didPanContent:` and `-translateContentContainerViewToPosition:animated:completion:` for the sliding animation from input of a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`